# Is polymer routing suitable for large scale website?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, reactjs, vue.js, polymer

I have one big project which contains different layouts and structures (it is like 100 different pages), but the core elements are the same (like header and menus). I would like to use javascript frameworks, so I found polymer. In polymer there is `<iron-ajax>`. Is it suit for my requirements?

Comment: what java scripts are you talking about?what do you mean by  frame works ?

Comment: yes i mean javaScript frameworks like react js,stencil, polymer , vue js

Comment: i see, so what do you want to do with them? compare them ?

Comment: i don't want to compare them. i already filter them and selected the polymer js. now i want to know is the polymer is suitable or not for the large website

Comment: why did you decide on polymer?

Comment: most of the js frameworks are for single page applications, you have 100 pages so you will have a hard time modifying those 100 to work as a single page aplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer could be yes. You can use all of the modern framerworks/libraries like Angular, React, Polymer and so on.

If you want to develop in Polymer big website, you will have to take care of few things. Otherwise your website will be very slow.

First, lazy load necessary elements for the current screen.

Second, build process (minify, uglify)

Third, service workers

These thing are important if you will do them right, your application will be very fast. For example, I have an administration with more than 30 screens and it's going very well (I didn't find any problem with the size of the website)

Another thing is routing. I am using [page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/) , because I like it's routing instead of `app-route` where it is a little bit confusing (at least for me).

You asked something about `iron-ajax`. I don't understand why are you asking just for this element? this one is used to call XHTTP requests on your server. It's a great element if you get used to it.

Polymer is very easy to use (propably the easiest one of the mentioned frameworks above) and has many elements already built and ready to use with nice documentation. If you really want to develop your website in Polymer, use version 2.x. DO NOT TRY TO USE 1.x (it will become obsolete and unsupported in browsers soon)

Comment: do you have any CRUD example using polymer 2.0 or any book or tutorial for that

Answer (score 0):

Polymer can be used to build large scale applications using `<app-route>` and would work similar to reactJs, angular or Vue. However, **Polymer** is not the same as these javascript frameworks. It is build for a different need.

Polymer is a framework to create  [HTML5 WebComponents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components), which is different from a javascript virtual component or light dom component (light dom is the dom we normaly use). HTML5 WebComponents are already supported natively by common browsers, if the browser dose not support WebComponents yet, when using polymer it will load Polyfills to give the same behavior in the browser.

Polymer creates reusable WebComponents in the shadow dom, which means the component created cannot or should not be interactive from other JavaScript or CSS. This can be seen when you inspect the HTML dom tree of a polymer component.

[image]

Libraries such as **jQuery** or native JavaScript querySelector can't look though the dom and find the component because it is not in the (Light) DOM tree. Thus making the component act and behave the same throughout all web applications it's being used.

Think of it as the select button on your file inputs in web application
[image]

If you want to style the button using normal CSS and javascript, you will have to use tweaks to do it. This is similer to a HTML5 WebComponents behavior

Now that being said, coming back to your question, Polymer can be used to create large scale websites. This means the whole application will become one polymer component. Polymer uses Lazy Loading of components, so the application wont be too heavy and will load relatively.

When creating your application, you have to keep in mind that you are using WebComponents and most JavaScript libraries that work on conventional WebApplications might not support WebComponents.